# Jquery Script Disabled for Screen Size less than 650px

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

How would I amend the below script to disable it for screen sizes less than 650px? I would like it to adapt to a browser being resized as well. Thanks!

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#lightSlider").lightSlider();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: See if the plugin has a destroy method and invoke it as per your need.

Comment: Ive looked through the documentation and haven't been able to locate anything. I'm using http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html. I'd appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Use Js [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

```
if (matchMedia) {
    var media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 650px)");
    media.addListener(change);
    change(media);
}

function change(media) {

    if (media.matches) {
        // run the code
    }
    else {

    }

}
```

Comment: Im sorry, can you give me the functioning code with my jquery above? I tried your code and had some unexpected results. Could be my error. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I tried that. When the page initially loads the script is inactive. When i resize browser it becomes active again.

Comment: @user2321744 oh sorry change `(max-width: 650px)` with `(min-width: 650px)`

Comment: Ok, it works great. However, it doesnt work on a browser resize. Any advice?

Comment: @user2321744 it shall work too somehow i got downvoted  for no reason :-(

Comment: Not sure how you got the downvote. Any input on the resize issue? Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

.resize() event related to browser resize

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    if(width <= 650){
        $('#screen').addClass('disabled'); // disable statement here
    }else{
        $('#screen').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```